# Rotating X-axis by 180 degrees

Tags: coordinate-systems

Rotating Y-axis by 180 degrees cause a flip for X and Z. Is that also valid that rotating the X-axis by 180 degrees cause a flip for Y and Z?

Comment: If you think about it, the whole x, y and z labelling are by convention, meaning that without these labels, the axes are virtually indistinguishable.

Comment: I think rotating the $Y$ axis by $180\deg$ will only cause $Z$ to flip...

Comment: When you say "rotate $y$-axis", which axis are you rotating it about? $x$ or $z$ ?